# Error: The argument type 'List<Color>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Color>' because 'List<Color>?' is nullable and 'List<Colo

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

error Error:

> The argument type 'List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List' because 'List?' is nullable and 'List

[image]

[image: error]

[image: the List]

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: Add you code instead of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alarm.gradientColors` is not guaranteed to be not `null`. If it can never be `null` you shouldn't define it as nullable. If it should be nullable but you are sure it's not `null` at that point of code, just add an `!` behind it like:

```
colors: alarm.gradientColors!
```

Answer (score 0):

I will encourage to do a null check before using `!` or just provide default value on null cases like

```dart
colors: alarm.gradientColors?? [Colors.red,Colors.blue], //default color
```